# Xamarin Listview with grouping won't scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, scroll, xamarin.forms

I'm working on my first Xamarin app. I want to make a listview with grouping and it succeeded. The only problem I have that it won't scroll. My other listview on another page scrolls without a problem, but my listview with grouping won't do that. I tried this both on an Android simulator as on my Android phone (I don't have a macbook or something to test on iOS), and it won't scroll on either of them. I looked it up but a lot of people put the listview in a scrollview, and I didn't do that.

This is my XAML code:

```
 <StackLayout Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">

        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" 
               FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Subtitle}" FontAttributes="Italic" 
               FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorColor="Accent" 
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsEnabled="False"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ScansGroup}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="4">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,7,10,1">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Location, StringFormat='{0}'}" 
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/y HH:mm}'}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ElapsedTimeOnLocation}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,7" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

I put it in an MVVM structure, and the grouping I did with a MVVM helper that I got from here https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/The-Xamarin-Show-12-MVVM-Helpers .
My code behind that is meant for the grouping is the following:

```
     public ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<string, ScanViewModel>> ScansGroup { get; } = 
new ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<string, ScanViewModel>>();

    void Group()
    {
         var grouped = from scan in Scans
                       group scan by scan.Day into scanGroup
                       select new Grouping<string, ScanViewModel>(scanGroup.Key, scanGroup);

         ScansGroup.ReplaceRange(grouped);

    }
```

**The grouping shows perfectly and the list too. The only problem is that 
I can't scroll**. Can someone help me?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza apparently I made a mondaymorning mistake and pasted the wrong code. Thanks for pointing it out. This question has now the right code.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. It is when not all items fit the screen, that I want to be able to scroll, but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out. There's nothing wrong with your grouping. In your code you set `IsEnabled="False"` to the `ListView`. It makes the listview's scroll ability to be handled just if you drag from an enabled item inside the `ListView`, and even thus, the scroll is like belittled and with a very bad user experience.

Just set your `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" 
          SeparatorColor="Accent" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          IsEnabled="True"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ScansGroup}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

I can't tell you if it was designed to be this way, or if it 's a bug, but it is the cause of your issue.

It's probable you have done this to handle some unwanted behavior. If so, let us know what is specifically your intend with this `IsEnabled="False"`, then we'll be able to help you with this.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes that was it! I disabled it because I don't want it to be a clickable list. It didn't occur to me that it would also disable the scrolling. I don't think there will be a simple workaround that makes the fields not clickable but the list stays scrollable?

Comment: @Marijke Unfortunately the `ListView` has no '`IsSelectable`' property. What if you subscribe the `ItemSelected` event and 'ignore' the selection on it (Like set `((ListView)sender)?.SelectedItem = null;` always)?

Comment: Thanks! Great idea!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't add the template for the group. Add this in the `<ListView>`

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
    <DataTemplate >
        <ViewCell Height="28" >
        <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Also, in the code bend or ViewModel, you need to bind to a group class of the items you want in the list such as:

```
public class GroupDetails : ObservableCollection<SomeItemsToShow>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Check out this Example for more details:
https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/

Comment: I edited my question and added my code behind. I use an MVVM helper for the grouping and did it according to a video that I also included in my question now. Seems that the GroupHeaderTemplate is not really necessary in that video? And if I try to implement your code, it gives me errors and can't get it to work properly. My problem isn't that my grouping isn't showing, I just can't scroll through the list when it doesn't fit my screen.

Comment: Did you check the link provided for extra details?
This is actually the official way of doing things. This method should be preferable to use instead of unofficial MVVM frameworks that needs to update and support the original release every time.

Comment: @Marijke , I didn't watch the video you used to create the list but I don't see an option to customize the group and the code looks complex